# Can you send data from an API body retrieved via cURL in PHP back to a ReactJS app

Tags: php, reactjs, json, curl, axios

I am currently working on a ReactJS app and I am attempting to use the Google Places nearby search API to return a list of places.

I first attempted to make this request from react and learned quickly that Google will not accept calls that do not come from a server. I figured the easiest way to go about making such a request would be to use cURL within a PHP script that I run using Axios withing ReactJS.

My Axios call is as follows:

```
 Axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'GPAPICall.php',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: { location: location, distance: distance },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

and the PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php

$location = $_POST['location'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];

    $endpoint = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?keyword=hotel&'.$location.'&type=bar'.$distance.'&key=AIzaSyDfWW64klgu-23CBAhsnplh8IpnQfm8CR4';
    $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = array();
    $response=json_decode($response_json, true);
?>
```

For a bit more context the app is grabbing user inputs from a Formik form and then sending them to that Axios i.e. { location: location, distance: distance } all of this is happening in a react component that I am rendering when a user clicks a button.

The console.log(response) is returning a 200 status but none of the Google places data is there. How can I go about getting the response data in my PHP script and then sending that data back to my ReactJS app for digestion?

Comment: Do you ever do anything with `$response` after you decode the JSON package? If not, this is why it's not getting to your ReactJS; you aren't sending it there!

Comment: I have tried echoing the $response to no avail. I guess this is kind of the question. How would I go about sending a php variable upstream to the ReactJS app?

Comment: @alias542 focus on the sending the `$response` part first, without the frontend/Axios part. `echo` should work, but maybe you're missing a `Content-Type` header. Try it with Postman or curl for example. The goal is to get the server to do the right thing, and then focus on the client.

Comment: The client is likely also wrong because it looks like your PHP script expects a 'form' request body, and your client is sending parameters as JSON.